# Como criar uma função em javascript para checar se um cookie foi gravado ou não?

Tags: javascript, html5, cookies

Sou aluno de sistemas de informação e estou aprendendo como criar cookies em javascrit utilizando funções e webstorege, mas estou com problemas na hora de criar a função para checar se um cookie foi gravado ou não.

Vejam o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays){
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*60*60*24*365));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires +";paths=/";
                alert("cookie inserido com sucesso");

            }

        function getCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
            var d = new Date();
            d.getTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*60*60*24*365));
            var expires = "expires" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname +"=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";paths=/";
            alert("Cookie exibido");

        }

    function checCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
            var d = new Date();
            d.getTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*60*60*24*365));
            var expires = "expires" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname +"=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";paths=/";
            alert("Cookie exibido");

        }

    function apagarCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
            var d = new Date();
            d.getTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*60*60*24*365));
            var expires = "expires" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname +"=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";paths=/";
            alert("Cookie exibido");

        }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Testes de Cookies</h1>
            <button id="btncookie" onclick="setCookie()">Gravar Cookies</button>
            <button id="btnExibir" onclick="getCookie()">Exibir Cookie</button>

        </center>
    </body> 
</html>
```

O que está errado na função checkCookie?

Como posso corrigir este erro?

Comment: Acredito que o Cookie só é verificável apos o recarregamento da página, mas posso estar errado.

Comment: Não sei se você estaria disposto a mudar , mas tente usar localStorage em Javascript, pois é mais seguro e mais fácil de utilizar.

Comment: A sua funcao "checkCookie" é exatamente igual a funcao "getCookie" isso é o que está errado.

Answer (score 0):

O código da função checkCookie que você colocou aqui está na realidade salvando um novo cookie.  Para realizar a leitura do mesmo você precisa acessar o objeto document.cookie, navegar pela string até encontrar o índice desejado. Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
function checkCookie(cname){
    var cookie = document.cookie.split(';');  
    var index= -1;

    cookie.forEach(function(c, i){

        var strIndex = c.split("=")[0]; 
        if (strIndex && strIndex.length > 0 && strIndex.trim() === cname)
            index = i;  
    });

    return index>-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanto suas funções `getCookie()` como `checkCookie()` estão salvando cookies ao invés de recuperá-los (se existirem).

Você também está passando "valores" para estas funções que na verdade não necessitam, a única informação relevante é o nome de um cookie, não é necessário passar a data de expiração porque se o cookie já expirou, logo não estará disponível para consulta.

Usando `replace()` e `RegExp()` sobre `document.cookie` você pode recuperar os valores de um dado cookie pelo seu nome (caso exista) ou, encapsulando esta lógica em uma função pode alternativamente retornar `false` caso não haja (não exista).

O exemplo a seguir expressa esta condição:

```
let getCookie(name) {
    return document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + name.replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1") || false
}
```

Você pode usar tanto para verificar se um cookie existe quanto para retornar (get) seu valor porque ele ira retornar o valor `{String}` ou `{Boolean}` `false` caso não exista:

```
// verificar dentro de condição `if`
if ( getCookie('nome_do_cookie') ) {
    // verdadeiro, cookie existe
}
// ou por atribuição
let cookieTarget = getCookie('nome_do_cookie')
if ( cookieTarget ) {
    // ...
}
// ou mesmo definir uma ação baseada na condição
function funcao001() {}
function funcao002() {}
let customHandler = (cookieTarget) ? funcao001 : funcao002
// usar
customHandler() {
    // fazer algo...
}
// caso o cookie exista a função retornará seu valor:
let customObject = {
    qualquercoisa: 'valor',
    cookie: getCookie('nome_do_cookie') // valor ({String}) ou "booleano" `false`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Aqui está um exemplo. A variável document.cookie guarda os cookies em formato key/value string. Para saber se o cookie está armazenado, voce pode usar o método interno para strings "match". Esse método aceita uma string e retorna um array se o valor existe e null se nao existe.

Veja um exemplo na funcao abaixo:

```js
/*
* It searches for a specified cookie at the DOM and it returns a boolean
* param _cookie: the cookie to be checked at the DOM
* return: boolean
*/
function hasCookie(_cookie) {
  return !!document.cookie.match(_cookie);
}

hasCookie("myexampleofcookie");
```